# How can I get underlying object for DbUpdateConcurrencyException.Entry

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm currently using Entity Framework 6. I am reloading a DbUpdateConcurrencyException.Entry but I also need to perform some task on the specific entry that cause the exception in the first place. I cannot figure out how to get access to that particular underlying object and would appreciate any assistance with this issue.

I have the following method:

```
public void ReloadEntries()
{
    foreach (var item in entries)
    {
        item.Reload();
        //TODO: cast back to original "Product" datatype so I can 
        //re-process a SPECIFIC property on underlying object here
    }
    entries.Clear();
}
```

I will change from the foreach later as I have since realized that 'entries' will always contain just 1 item.

Comment: Please provide (code) what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've edited to show just the method I'm working with. I don't have any code for what I have tried so far (to solve the problem) as I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: Maybe you can use `entry.CurrentValues["PropertyName"]` (and/or `entry.OriginalValues`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need something like:

```
try 
{
  item.Reload();
  //TODO: re-process property on underlying object here
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) 
{
  // process on ex.Entries[0].Entity or
  // ex.Entries[0].Entity.OriginalValues
  ((DataType)ex.Entries[0].Entity).Property = value;

  // if your object context is still open, you could try to re-submit after trying the 
  // entity
  ctx.Attach(ex.Entries[0].Entity);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This link might be helpful in what to do with that Entries list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696410(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the behavior I want is to have this entry somehow cast back to it's original Product datatype so i can have access to it's (Product) properties.

Comment: Yeah... then you would just cast ex.Entries[0].Entity to the entity whose properties you want. So something like (Product)ex.Entries[0].Entity or if you wanted to get specific properties ex.Entries[0].OriginalValues.Items["Product.PropertyName"] would be the value you wanted to get.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I edited your answer a bit just to make it answer my question a little better.